# How to make font awesome icon clickable event

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
  pointer-events: all;    
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1200;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd; display: block;}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/js/all.js" data-auto-replace-svg="nest"></script>    
<body>

<div id="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn fas fa-bars fa-2x" onclick="myFunction()" style="visibility: visible;"></button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
  <a href=""> DROPDOWN CONTENT </a>
    <a href=""> DROPDOWN CONTENT </a>
      <a href=""> DROPDOWN CONTENT </a>
  </div>  

</div>

</body>
```

Dear stackoverflow, I am currently coding a top nav bar, with this menu drop-down button, this code works fine, however when clicking the WHITE part of the font awesome icon, it does not trigger the javascript event.

Is there any way to make the menu icon clickable too? or let it be invisible to mouse pointer events.

thank you x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that the icon is rendered as a `svg` within the `button`.  This is an independent element and the `onclick` attribute does not apply to it.

The best way to solve this is to explicitly set the `pointer-events` to `none` for the icon SVG:

```
.dropbtn > svg {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

The `pointer-events` property dictates how the UI should respond to events on the object.  By setting it to `none`, we are saying that this object does not process events and they are therefore passed to the object underneath the SVG.

The working snippet showing this can be seen below.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
  pointer-events: all;    
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1200;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd; display: block;}

.show {display: block;}

.dropbtn > svg {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/js/all.js" data-auto-replace-svg="nest"></script>    
<body>

<div id="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn fas fa-bars fa-2x" onclick="myFunction()" style="visibility: visible;"></button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
  <a href=""> DROPDOWN CONTENT </a>
    <a href=""> DROPDOWN CONTENT </a>
      <a href=""> DROPDOWN CONTENT </a>
  </div>  

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Wow, I will have to remember this! I was working on this for the whole weekend, Thank you so much for the solution x

Answer (score 0):

I mean this could be a simple solution or i might be wrong but this might work. Putting this css code on the menu icon:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: unfortunately, this makes the whole button not clickable. Will keep trying x